# Perform a strpos with a namespace

Tags: php, string

I tried to run this code thinking that `strpos` was working giving to me the position of the following string in this namespace, but it return false why this happen? 
My goal was check if that given name is contained  in that string / namespace.

```
$string = "Core\Same\Class";

var_dump(strpos('Class',$string)); // return false
```

Comment: reverse your parameters http://us1.php.net/strpos

Comment: Ahhhh yes exactly noob question sorry about it

Comment: It isn't a namespace to strops, just a simple string comprising a series of characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Looks like you gave the arguments to strpos() in the wrong order.

Comment: Ahhhh yes exactly noob question sorry about it